# iOS 8 :MFMailComposeViewController automatic called cancel button

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

iOS 7 email send work perfectly but iOS 8 view automatic disappear and send button also not enable.

```
error is :timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService
```

Comment: which xcode you have used to test app? and its perfectly working in iOS 8 device..

Comment: xcode 6 and ios 8 working perfectly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got answer,

this is the xcode problem. try to **run on iOS 8 updated devise or iPhone 6** then check. it's work perfectly.